# DDL script into OR modell

Tags: orm, fluent-nhibernate, ddl

Is there a tool which convert a **DDL script into an OR model**?
I know about some commercial reverse engineering software doing this from a database.

But what i am looking for is more like an open source library which can be part of my c# code. Pretty much like hbm2dll, except the other way round.

Comment: why not create a private database with the ddl script and use one of the reverse engineering tools available?

Comment: I am doing this now but i was just wondering if there is something else. I thought of a small tool or library which could be part of my application instead of a too mighty external software. thank you anyway

Comment: it might be useful but since ddl sql can have totally different syntax for the same effect while querying the database gives the same easy readable results every time